# Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
E:/smnd/client/src/components/auth/Login.js:69

```
function mapStateToProps (state){
      return{
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
      }
    }
```

this is the code of Login.js

```
import React, {Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import {Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {login} from '../../actions/auth';
// import {isAuthenticated} from '../../reducers/auth';

 

const Login = ({login, isAuthenticated}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const { email, password} = formData;

    const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
           login(email,password);
    };
    
    // redirected if logged in 
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />;
    }
  

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign In</h1>
      <p className="lead"><i className="fas fa-user"></i> Sign Into Your Account</p>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value={email} onChange={ e => onChange(e)}  />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={ e => onChange(e)} 
            
          />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
      </form>
      <p className="my-1">
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Sign Up</Link>
      </p>
        </Fragment>
        );
    };

    Login.propTypes = {
      login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
    }

    // const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    //   isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    // });

     function mapStateToProps (state){
      return{
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
      }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {login}) (Login);
```

Comment: You're not giving us sufficient information, please attach more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't set the initial state of `auth` in the redux store. So you need to add optional chaining like this:

```
isAuthenticated: state.auth?.isAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in the login reducer of redux store , you have provided the "isAuthenticated" as initialState like the below..

const **initialState** = {
*isAuthenticated: false,*
};

function *loginReducer*(state = *initialState*, action){
....
}

Also make sure that you have included the loginReducer in the "**combineReducers**" function , if you are using **multiple** reducers for your redux store